# start-process, ArgumentList issue via powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to invoke cmd via powershell and pass on arguments that will change directory on cmd to c:\pilot

Sample code that I tried doing this via start-process:

```
Start-Process "C:\Users\su\AppData\Roaming\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk" -ArgumentList 'C:\pilot'
```

so after running this, it appears to pop up a new cmd window, but doesn't change the directory to `c:\pilot`, is there a special format in sending arguments to cmd?

Comment: `Start-Process` has a `-WorkingDirectory` parameter; you must use that to change the directory; by contrast, `-ArgumentList` passes arguments through to the target program (if the target is a _program_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an earlier revision of your question:

> ultimately I am trying to change directory and also pass on an command for execution on the 2nd window without closing the second window.

The following opens a stay-open `cmd.exe` console window ("Command Prompt") in working directory `C:\pilot` and executes command `date /t`

```
 Start-Process cmd -WorkingDirectory C:\pilot -ArgumentList '/k', 'date /t'
```